# How to pass arguments to functions in PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the below PowerShell script

```
Function Publish
{
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]
        $RELEASEDIR,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]
        $SERVICENAME,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]
        $SERVER
    )

    Get-ChildItem "$RELEASEDIR\*"
    $service = Get-Service -Name $SERVICENAME -Computername $SERVER -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $service.Status
}
Publish
```

How I am executing this:

```
PS C:\Release\RPCPS> .\RPCPublish.ps1 -RELEASEDIR "C:\Location" -SERVICENAME "value" -SERVER "server"
cmdlet Publish at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
RELEASEDIR:
```

Even after passing arguments while executing, the script is expecting it again. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: .\RPCPublish.ps1 =/= your function `publish`

Comment: Did not understand

Comment: [dotsource](https://ss64.com/ps/source.html) the script and do `publish -arg1 -arg2 -arg3`, also, consider changing function name to verb-noun format

Comment: You script does not accept arguments. Your `publish` function _inside your script_ does. The arguments you are passing to your script are not getting to your function hence why it starts asking for them.

Comment: how should I execute it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is creating a function, "Publish", (lines 1-17) and then calling it with no parameters (line 18). Since you've defined parameters as mandatory (lines 4, 7, 10), failing to supply the parameters when you call the function (line 18) causes PowerShell to request values for the unsupplied parameters.

Supplying parameters to the script file itself does not help; there is no mechanism for "automagically" passing those parameters to anything within the script (you would have to explicitly code the script for that).

As Matt suggested in the comments, dot-source your script after deleting line 18, and then call your function explicitly, passing the parameters (`publish -RELEASEDIR "C:\Release\Batchfile" -SERVICENAME "AmazonSSMAgent" -SERVER "10.0.1.91"`).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to execute the script by calling the .ps1 as in your example, there is no need to use a function. Your script should look just like this:

```
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $RELEASEDIR,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $SERVICENAME,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $SERVER
    )
Get-ChildItem "$RELEASEDIR\*"
$service = Get-Service -Name $SERVICENAME -Computername $SERVER -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$service.Status
```

The parameters are passed directly to the script and can be used there.

If, on the other hand, you want to establish a (reusable) function, remove just the last line from your script, which calls the function without parameters (which is why it asks for the mandatory parameters every time).

If you remove the last line, you can call the script without parameters once. After that you have a new function `Publish` in your current session, which you can then call with

```
Publish -RELEASEDIR "C:\Release\Batchfile" -SERVICENAME "AmazonSSMAgent" -SERVER "10.0.1.91"
```

independent of the script file.

Comment: How can I execute the same in Jenkins

Comment: No idea, I don't do Jenkins. Maybe this will be helpful: https://hodgkins.io/automating-with-jenkins-and-powershell-on-windows-part-1

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding your requirement is to run the ***function***, and you have to compile the scripts also in Jenkins.

You can do something like this:

Let's say your script name is *RPCPublish.ps1* and the path is *D:\Folder*.

And I can see your function name is ***Publish***.

So in your case,

```
powershell -command "& { D:\folder\RPCPublish.ps1; Publish }"
```

You can pass the parameters after this in the script block.

Answer (score 0):

I used a PowerShell plugin (*[PowerShell](https://plugins.jenkins.io/powershell)*) and executed the same.

```
. "C:\Release\RPCPS\RPCPublish.ps1"
FUunctionName -RELEASEDIR "C:\bin\Release" -SERVICENAME "Service" -SERVER "$env:SERVER" -DISPLAYNAME "Services Air" -BINPATH "D:\Build\Project.exe" -DESCRIPTION "This service hosts Air service" -DESTINATION "d$\Build\"
```

Comment: Does the plugin have a name?

Comment: @PeterMortensen https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin